# How to count length of text in all children of a div in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

In Cypress I have a bunch of articles, and I would like to test that they all have at least X characters or Y words inside the `.content`-div.

The structure of the `.content`-div looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <p> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
  <p>
    Adipiscing elit suspendisse eu nibh.
  </p>
</div>
```

If I current do this:

```
cy.get( '.content' ).its( 'length' ).should( 'be.gte', 5 );
```

But this yields the error:

> expected 2 to be at least 5

Since it counts the tags inside the div, the two `<p>`-tags. Instead of counting the words inside these `<p>`-tags.

How do I count all words/characters (either is fine), in all children (and ideally also childrens children recursively)?

... So a function that returned `10` for above-given example.

It could be super-cool to have a command with it.

Comment: Cypress seems to have an `.invoke('text')` that might be useful, it's shown in their FAQ's [here](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-get-an-element-s-text-contents).

Answer (score 3):

I would use a word regex and check the match length.

```js
cy.get('.content')
  .invoke('text')    // include children
  .match(/[\w-]+/g)  // match words
  .its('length)
  .should('be.gt', 5)
  .and('eq', 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly iterate over the `p` tags using `each` and then invoke text and then assert its length.

```js
cy.get('.content > p').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).invoke('text').its('length').should('be.gte', 5)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the spaces,

```js
cy.get('.content')
  .find('p')     // children + children's children (any <p> under .content)
  .each($p => {
    const words = $p.text().split(' ').length +1
    expect(words.length).to.be.gte(5)
  })
```